# image capturing and uploading on server and fetching from server not working in angular js and ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I want to capture the image and after capturing it should be uploaded to server and want to fetch the same from the server and want to display it in one place i.e `$scope.pictureUrl="http://placehold.it/100x100"`.Similarly I want to select image from the gallery and want to upload to server but my code doesnt work.
So below is my code. I have already referred many questions regarding this on stackoverflow but in vain . It gives success alert but when i see my server it doesnt show any image uploaded.Please suggest me the changes.

```
  $scope.pictureUrl = "http://placehold.it/100x100";
    $scope.pictureUrl2="http://placehold.it/100x100";

  $scope.takePicture = function () {
      var options = {
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
      };
      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
          //console.log('camera data: ' + angular.toJSON(imageData));
          $scope.imgdata = imageData;
          $scope.pictureUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
         // var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
          var url = '';
          var fd = new FormData();

          //previously I had this
          //angular.forEach($scope.files, function(file){
          //fd.append('image',file)
          //});

          fd.append('image', $scope.imgdata);

          $http.post(url, fd, {

                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  headers: {
                      'Content-Type': undefined
                  }
              })
              .success(function (data, status, headers) {
                  $scope.pictureUrl2 = data.resource_uri; //set it to the response we get
                alert("Success");
              })
              .error(function (data, status, headers) {

              })

      });
  }

  $scope.takePhoto = function () {
    var options = {
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
    };
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
      $scope.imgdata=imageData;
      $scope.pictureUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
        //$scope.blobImg = dataURItoBlob($scope.pictureUrl);
      window.alert("Picture Captured .. !!");
    }, function (err) {
      window.alert('Error:' + err.message);
    });
  };
```

Plugins are installed properly.Camera and gallery are initiating but unable to upload :(

Comment: *"image capturing and uploading on server and fetching from server not working in angular js and ionic"* - which part of this is not working? Can you break this up and try to do one thing at a time?

Comment: okay ,if i want to break ..then the uploading part is not working after capturing image from camera . it shows success but actualy it is not uploaded on server

Comment: @Siddhesh Kalgaonkar are you sending the image in base64 formate

Comment: no i am not sending the image in base64 format

Comment: what i want is after capturing two images it should be sent to the server and after fetching the images one should be placed in `$scope.pictureurl` and other should be placed in `$scope.pictureurl2`

Comment: do any one have simple way of doing the same above thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using destination type as

`destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,`

So in **imageData** contains only base64 values so you can assign that value to your object and you can use for post method.

When you are trying to get the data of base64 from server

`'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;` (**Note** here imageData is the variable that contains base64 string)

In this way we can display image from server